# public_send method_missing in spree with postmark

Tags: heroku, spree, postmark

After install postmark gem and edit config/application as instruct. I try forget password in Spree but error shown in User Screen. 
At the heroku logs I found the step public_send shown method_missing.

Don't know what missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was a new web setup. The return email from postmark send back to that email asked to activate before send mail would work.

So I just click Confirm Signature then try again it worked.